# How to implement RSMasked Label property for android?

Tags: android, transparent

I have seen the  RSMaskedLabel control in ios as you can observe its significance in [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rsmaskedlabel) link. I want to implement this in my android application. I tried giving (android:alpha="0") but its taking its transparent as white box,but I want to implement as like in the below picture.

Is there any property for textView in android.

RSMasked label property in android.

I didn't find anything in google regarding similar properties in android.I just likes to know whether any properties in android for achieving this task.

Please refer to the Image and the link which I posted. Please suggest me in solving this issue.

This is the code used in iOS:

```
#import "RSMaskedLabel.h"

@interface RSMaskedLabel()
- (void) RS_commonInit;
- (void) RS_drawBackgroundInRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end

@implementation RSMaskedLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
        [self RS_commonInit];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
        [self RS_commonInit];
    return self;
}

- (void)RS_commonInit
{
    [super setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setOpaque:NO];
}

- (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor
{
    // text color needs to be white for masking to work
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // let the superclass draw the label normally
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, CGRectGetHeight(rect)));

    // create a mask from the normally rendered text
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image), CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(image), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image), CGImageGetDataProvider(image), CGImageGetDecode(image), CGImageGetShouldInterpolate(image));

    CFRelease(image); image = NULL;

    // wipe the slate clean
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, mask);

    CFRelease(mask);  mask = NULL;

    [self RS_drawBackgroundInRect:rect];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}

- (void) RS_drawBackgroundInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // this is where you do whatever fancy drawing you want to do!
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}

@end
```

using the above class for getting the below image effect:

```
 RSMaskedLabel *meLbl =[[RSMaskedLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.5,circle_view.frame.origin.y+circle_view.frame.size.height+27.5,239.5,51)]
     [meLbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
                meLbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Bold" size:20];
                meLbl.layer.opacity= 71.0f/100.0f;
                meLbl.numberOfLines=2;

                meLbl.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
                meLbl.highlighted=YES;
                [meLbl setText:popobj1.title];
```

Please suggest for implementing this in android.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried entering the textColor as android.R.color.transparent

Answer (score 0):

`android:textColor="@android:color/tranparent"` if using the xml layout

or use `textView.setTextColor(android.R.color.transparent);`

I haven't tried this, but if you make your textView transparent (or just like having no background)

and then make a span that has a [BackgroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.html) of white and a [ForegroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html) of Transparent, does that work?

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/awesometext"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Then later on in the code try something like this:

```
String text = "My Awesome text";
SpannableString spannable = SpannableString.valueOf(text);
spannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(getColor(android.R.color.white)), 0, spannable.length() - 1, Spannable.INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getColor(android.R.color.transparent)), 0, spannable.length() - 1, Spannable.INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: I didnt worked for me,in my case I have an scrollview(which is of multiple colors) and on top of it I have an transparent image with opacity 0.7. And on top of tranparent image I have an textview( I want this text color to be same as my scrollview background).

Comment: iOS developers has used some RSMaskedLabel,if you want I can post that code also. They used some Third party class for achieving this but I cannot able to find anything similiar in android.

Comment: ok so that's not what you stated previously, you need to specify your layout. Can't read your mind on this

Comment: sorry,can you able to get me now

Comment: Let me know if that helps more

Comment: I didnt understand what you are trying to explain.can you please describe

Comment: put some effort into it. not sure where you are running your code from, but `getColor()` is a method on something that has access to a `Resources` object. You could also just use `Color.White` and `Color.Transparent` repectively

Comment: The method getColor(int) is undefined for the type ScrollingFeedmode.doInBack, I am doing all this in onPostExecute()

Comment: Dude just use the static constants. Color.White and Color.Transparent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44300/discussion-between-user1891910-and-greg-giacovelli)